# Using PL/SQL to Select Everything from Table

Tags: plsql

So in an assignment of mine, I have to select everything from inside of a specific table and output it. The example code that we were given is:

```
declare
    current_bldg_code varchar2(5);
    cursor location_cursor is
        select room
        from location
        where bldg_code = current_bldg_code;
    current_room location.room%type;
begin
    current_bldg_code := 'LIB';
    open location_cursor;
    loop
        fetch location_cursor into current_room;
        exit when location_cursor%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(
            'The current room is ' || 
             current_bldg_code || ' ' || 
            current_room
    );
    end loop;
    close location_cursor;
end;
/
```

Now I came up with my own version to go off of the tables we are using and I am getting no data. This is what I have:

SOLVED:

```
declare
    c_first varchar2(30000);
    c_last varchar2(30000);
    c_mi char(10000);
    c_address varchar2(30000);
    c_dphone varchar2(10000);
    cursor customer_cursor is
        select c_first, c_mi, c_last, c_address, c_dphone
        from customer;
begin
    open customer_cursor;
    dbms_output.put_line('Clearwater Traders Mailing List');
    loop
        fetch customer_cursor into c_first, c_last, c_mi, c_address, c_dphone;
        exit when customer_cursor%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(c_first || ' ' || c_last || ' ' || c_mi || ' ' || c_address || ' ' || c_dphone);
    end loop;
    close customer_cursor;
end;
/
```

Comment: All the `current_` variables in your `WHERE` clause are `NULL`, so it cannot match anything. You did not initialize these variables. Do you really want a `WHERE` at all?

Comment: Note that in the example the variable was initialized:  `current_bldg_code := 'LIB'`

Comment: Honestly have no clue what I am doing. I am supposed to select the following variables from the customer table. I know how to do it in regular sql, but can't figure it out in pl/sql with a cursor. But ya, I have no specific searches I am to make. I am supposed to pull everything from the table.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I can just declare c_first and so on, get rid of the where clauses, and just output what I selected?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use ROWTYPE variable in the cursor:

```
declare
    c_customer customer%ROWTYPE;
    cursor customer_cursor is
        select *
        from customer;
begin
    open customer_cursor;
    dbms_output.put_line('Clearwater Traders Mailing List');
    loop
        fetch customer_cursor into c_customer;
        exit when customer_cursor%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(c_customer.first || ' ' || c_customer.last || ' ' || c_customer.mi || ' ' || c_customer.address || ' ' || c_customer.dphone);
    end loop;
    close customer_cursor;
end;
```